# Show default image if image is not found

Tags: excel, vba

This code allows me to insert an image. I write in TXT_CODE and look for it in the file IMAGES.

I want is to use a default image in case the image is not in the file.

For instance, the image should say: Image is not available.

```
Set Img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Images\" & Txt_Code.Value & ".png")
With Img
    'Resize Picture to fit in the range....
    .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Fila).Left
    .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Fila).Top
    .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    .Width = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Fila).Width
    .Height = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Fila).Height
    .Placement = 1
    .PrintObject = True
End With
```

I would like to do it with an IF conditional, something like...

```
If Txt_Code.Value is not found in file Images then
    show default_Image.png
else
    the code above
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim r As Range, Img As Object, sFilePath As String, sFileDefault As String, sFile As String, Fila As Long
    sFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Images\" & Txt_Code.Value & ".png"
    Fila = 5
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Fila)
    If Dir(sFilePath) <> "" Then
        sFile = sFilePath
    Else
        MsgBox "Image Not Found", vbExclamation
        sFileDefault = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Images\DefaultImage.png"
        If Dir(sFileDefault) = "" Then
            MsgBox "No Default Image. Process Cancelled.", vbExclamation: Exit Sub
        Else
            sFile = sFileDefault
        End If
    End If
    Set Img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(sFile)
    With Img
        .Left = r.Left
        .Top = r.Top
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Width = r.Width
        .Height = r.Height
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: ++ Like the way you thought of handling `MsgBox "No Default Image. Process Cancelled.", vbExclamation: Exit Sub` Nice :)

Comment: @YasserKhalil the code you provided doesn't show the default image =( [link](https://postimg.cc/Z9G2TGt6) Nothing hapens if the image code is not found.

Comment: The commanbutton is on userform I guess. Maybe you have commandbutton on Worksheet ( I am not sure ).

Comment: @YasserKhalil The commanbutton is on userform. I think the problem is that I'm using a combobox to look for a product in a table, when I select a product, the code number pass to TXT_CODE automatically, for some reason that is causing some sort of problem because If I write the code number directly in  TXT_CODE the DEFAULTIMAGE shows. Why could it be?

Comment: I have no idea exactly but try using `Cstr` function in that part `Cstr(Txt_Code.Value)`